# MSSQL Как сформировать запрос на выборку данных

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужна помощь в решении данного вопроса. 
Имеется БД, с такими таблицами:
Группа - **SGROUP**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Преподаватели - **TEACHER**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Задание:**
*Вывести имена преподавателей и дату их приема на работу, удовлетворяющих следующему условию:

- они являются кураторами групп 1 курса или групп с рейтингом больше 15
  И
- они имеют должность профессора или доцента И
- у них зарплата (salary+commission) меньше 1000 или больше 2000.*

Вот то что я "накодил", но не работает так как надо:

```
SELECT TEACHER.Name, TEACHER.Hiredate
 FROM SGROUP, TEACHER
 WHERE TEACHER.TchNo = SGROUP.Curator AND SGROUP.Rating > 15 OR SGROUP.Course = '1' AND TEACHER.Post = 'Professor' OR Post = 'Assistant professor'
 AND Salary+Commission < 1000 OR Salary+Commission > 2000
```

Comment: Почитайте про приоритеты операторов. Или хотя бы расставьте скобки в секции WHERE.

Comment: @Akina Понял, спасибо. Пошел читать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.Name, t.Hiredate
FROM TEACHER t
WHERE  t.Post IN ('Professor', 'Assistant professor')
    AND ( t.Salary + t.Commission < 1000
        OR t.Salary + t.Commission > 2000
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM SGROUP g
        WHERE t.TchNo = g.Curator
            AND ( g.Rating > 15
                OR g.Course = '1'
            )
    )
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо.